# nodejs - Stress test zeromq sockets

Tags: node.js, performance, tcp, zeromq, benchmarking

I have a zeromq rep socket server set up and want to stress test how many requests per second it can process.

What is a good way of going about this?

I can just write a script that fires N number of requests and take the total time, but that would include the time spent in the concurrency overhead on the benchmark-client. Should I spin up a separate process for each request?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with zeromq socket server before but I did stress test last time using Apache JMeter https://jmeter.apache.org/ to my backend API. In here, I can specify how many requests and see the time duration when all requests finished.

This link may also help
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-perform-stress-test-jmeter